# Retrieve interesting parts of a video

Tags: video

I have a recording from security camera at a corridor in my house. It mostly just shows the empty corridor, but somewhere there should be a thief. Is there any software that would be able to cut these parts of the video that contain no motion? I am aware of openCV, is there any solution not involving writing my own script?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, because a couple of our staff did a very similar project that does [surveillance analysis using motion detection](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t9042-). I'm not posting this as an answer because the project is for programmers, since our main product is a programming library. So I'm afraid you can't use it without our library. If anyone knows of a ready end-user app that does this, please post a reply.